# displaying all cmd.exe text to textbox

Tags: vb.net, ftp, cmd, output

I've search high and low looking for a way to display all text from FTP.exe to a richtextbox. so far  i've only been able to do is display the output code. the idea is to run the test and display and capture to a file which hasn't been a problem except i can't seem to display all text as you would see it in Command.Hoping to see all text when done. Please Help!!

Here is he code:
    Private Sub Rectangle1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Rectangle1.Click
        Dim p As New Process()
        With p
            .StartInfo.Arguments = " -s:c:\dsl\ftptest\speed1.txt 65.40.220.20"
            .StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
            .StartInfo.FileName = "ftp"
            .StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
            .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            .Start()

```
        Dim StErr As StreamReader = .StandardError
        Dim StOut As StreamReader = .StandardOutput

        While (Not StOut.EndOfStream)
            Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("{0}", StOut.ReadLine() & vbCrLf))
        End While

        .WaitForExit()

    End With
End Sub
```

End Class

Here is the output from the code:
User (65.40.220.20:(none)): Hash mark printing On  ftp: (2048 bytes/hash mark) .

hash
get test.1meg

#

cd upload
put test.1meg

#

close
bye

Here is What I'm looking for:

C:\DSL\FTPTEST>call FTP -s:c:\dsl\FTPtest\speed1.txt 65.40.220.20
Connected to 65.40.220.20.
220-

This server is provided as a EMBARQ Speedtest server for DSL customers only.

Any other use is prohibited.

You may login using anonymous ftp and download the test files to determine your speed.

You may upload the same files to the upload directory to test your upload speed.
 You may only upload the files that you previously downloaded from this server.

You cannot download anything from the upload directory.

Remember, some ftp programs measure speed in bytes per second.
 DSL speeds are measured in bits per second.  There are 8 bits in a byte.
 If you can download at 64 kilobytes per second then that is the same as
 512 kilobits per second.

220 65.40.220.20 FTP server ready
User (65.40.220.20:(none)):
331 Anonymous login ok, send your complete email address as your password.

230-

This server is provided as a EMBARQ Speedtest server for DSL customers only.

Any other use is prohibited.

You may login using anonymous ftp and download the test files to determine your speed.

You may upload the same files to the upload directory to test your upload speed.
 You may only upload the files that you previously downloaded from this server.

You cannot download anything from the upload directory.

Remember, some ftp programs measure speed in bytes per second.
 DSL speeds are measured in bits per second.  There are 8 bits in a byte.
 If you can download at 64 kilobytes per second then that is the same as
 512 kilobits per second.

230 Anonymous access granted, restrictions apply.
ftp> hash
Hash mark printing On  ftp: (2048 bytes/hash mark) .
ftp> get test.1meg
200 PORT command successful
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for test.1meg (1048576 bytes)

#

#

#

ftp: 1048576 bytes received in 5.96Seconds 175.94Kbytes/sec.
ftp>
ftp> cd upload
250 CWD command successful
ftp> put test.1meg
200 PORT command successful
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for test.1meg

#

#

#

226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 1048576 bytes sent in 5.98Seconds 175.23Kbytes/sec.
ftp>
ftp>

Comment: User (65.40.220.20:(none)): Hash mark printing On  ftp: (2048 bytes/hash mark) .


hash
get test.1meg
################################################################################################################################
cd upload
put test.1meg
################################################################
close
bye
This is what it Display's didn't show on post. Sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might be able to redirect the output of your command to a file. e.g, at the end of the command add (assuming that you have a directory c:\temp)

```
your command here > c:\temp\TestOutput.text
```

Then in your program, add a file system watcher to watch that file and load it into the textbox when it changes. If you're doing this lots of time then you might have to dynamically generate a filename and delete the files when no-longer needed.

Comment: I was working on the code on a different machine today only to have the same code do what I wanted different OS. I've been working on windows 7 and today's computer was windows 8. So I move the files back to the windows 7 computer to have it not work again. A little confused at this point. Maybe it's a setting in Visual Basic express or something in the OS coding?